# PHP Array Not Working Properly in JS File

Tags: javascript, php, json

I wrote this script in PHP:

```
$mainArray = array();
$storageArray = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $array = array($row["TransactionAmount"], $row["AccountBalance"], $row["TransactionDate"]);
    array_push($storageArray, $array);
}
$paginationArray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($storageArray); $i++) {
    if (sizeof($paginationArray) < 15) {
        array_push($paginationArray, $storageArray[$i]);
    } else {
        array_push($mainArray, $paginationArray);
        $paginationArray = array();
    }
}
print_r($mainArray);
```

What happens is that when I try to access elements of the array, instead of doing that it access each character to the array as if it were iterating through a string. If [["Hello"], ["World"]] is the array sent from PHP, when I do data[0] in the JS file it will literally grab the first brace instead of grabbing "Hello". I have no idea why this is because I have never had it happen before. What gives? It isn't a string and I've encoded and decoded the JSON on both ends to see if that solved the properly but get nothing.

Comment: Are you calling the from Ajax?

Comment: If you are calling the script from Ajax then you may use `echo json_encode($mainArray);` in PHP and in Ajax use  `var array = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: Yes I am. What's the problem?

Comment: All I'm getting is an unexpected token error with this.

Comment: ...and it looks like if I even have JSON.parse() present in the success call at all this error shows up- even if the variable assigned to it isn't even used.

Comment: Please share your JavaScript Code and the complete error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

PHP `print_r` outputs a human readable information about a variable. Your output would be a string which would look something like this:

```
Array
(
    [a] => apple
    [b] => banana
    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
        )
)
```

To access the data you put in the PHP array in JS, it should be in a format JS can understand - let's say JSON.

So, in place of `print_r`, you should use

`echo json_encode($mainArray);`

This will create a json string.

Convert it to JS object by using `JSON.parse` in your front end.

Comment: All I'm getting is an uncaught syntax: unexpected token error with this. The JSON string IS being sent, but when I try to parse it, I get the error.

Comment: Looks like your server is interfering with the output. Please post here what you see when you put the php scripts address in the browser address bar.

Comment: The only warning I get is this: Warning: mysqli::close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\BankAccountManager\transactionClass.php on line 39. However, the data is grabbed and converted into a JSON string.

Comment: Your php output is not pure json. Remove the warning.

Comment: Aha... I thought as much. I had an unnecessary connection close that was getting grabbed along with everything else. Thanks, man.